# Responding to tick events during d3 transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an svg line element which points to an svg rectangle element.  When the rectangle moves, the line needs to follow it.  Is there a way to do this when the rectangle is moved with a d3 transition?  I'm looking for something that allows me to respond to each tick of the rectangle's transition.  An analogous thing is provided for [force layout simulations](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-on):

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
     .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
     .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
     .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

});
```

This can be used to move two elements at each step in time.  Can it be done for arbitrary transitions in the absence of a layout?  It seems like [`transition.each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each) could do this if it could listen for a transition tick event, but it can only listen for transition start and end events.

I don't want to set a separate transition on the line element because I need to guarantee that the two elements move completely concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `tick` event for transitions, so you can't do exactly what you want. There should be no need for this however -- you can simply add a transition to the line end in the same way as to the rectangle. The code would look something like this.

```
rect.transition().attr("x", newX).attr("y", newY);
line.transition().attr("x2", newX).attr("y2", newY);
```

Answer (score 2):

The method for invoking a function at each tick of a transition is [`transition.tween()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_tween).

You pass a name and a factory function. The name is just an identifier. The factory function is called once for each element in the transition, and should return a function to be called on that element for each tick.